# what's the meaning of the SO's Data table

Tags: dataexplorer

Well,I have got data of the Stackexchange.
LINK: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new
There're several tables.
Q:in the table posthistory,what's the posthistorytypeid meaning ?
Q:there're some brief intruduction about these tables?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

There's also a readme.txt file between all the different dumps of stackexchange-sites. In this file all columns are described in detail.

Comment: You can find most details on this page: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede